# writing data to target in gnu make file

Tags: makefile

could you please let me know what is wrong with the the following

the file first has the data one. and I am trying to write hello to firstfile. it is not working.

`firstfile:first
    echo "hello" ;  > $@`

but the following one works

`firstfile:first
    for f in $^;do echo "hello" ; done  > $@`

could you please let me know what is the difference.

Comment: `echo "hello" ;  > $@` -> `echo "hello"   > $@`. One command. Not two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`;` is a command separator in the shell. So your first recipe:

```
firstfile:first
    echo "hello" ;  > $@
```

is equivalent to:

```
firstfile:first
    echo "hello"    # writes "hello" to your console
    > $@            # writes an empty string to `firstfile`
```

Change it to:

```
firstfile:first
    echo "hello"  > $@
```

Comment: @sri Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

It seems echo "hello"; is executed first then some blank is written to the firstfile. and the for loop echo command result hello may be taken as string hello and the string is written to the firstfile. could please conform it.